Flask app errors on all other endpoints except for root - what am I missing
I've developed a Flask app that runs perfectly on my laptop - all endpoints work perfectly and I've also created several HTML pages that interact with the Flask API endpoints.
The next step is to deploy this (permanently) to AWS EC2 (Ubuntu). I've followed this tutorial about creating a Flask app https://plainenglish.io/community/deploying-a-flask-application-on-ec2-dab5d3 and the "hello world" works perfectly.
I replaced app.py with my own code and again the / endpoint works fine - but no other endpoint does, I keep getting 404 errors.
I've been trying to narrow the reason, but even if I create a /test endpoint it doesn't work (via a browser and the public IP) and returns a 404.  If I SSH to the EC2 and run
curl HTTP://127.0.0.1:8000/test

it works - I can see the HTML being returned.
What am I missing?
this is the current app.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, make_response, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, abort, fields, marshal_with
from sqlalchemy import *
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


@app.route("/")
def home_page():
    return render_template("api_home.html")
    
@app.route('/test')
def testing_area():
    return render_template('test.html')

@app.route('/custom1')
def custom1():
    return render_template('custom_interface_1.html')

@app.route('/custom2')
def custom2():
    return render_template('custom_interface_2.html')

@app.route('/custom3')
def custom3():
    return render_template('custom_interface_3.html')

@app.route('/custom4')
def custom4():
    return render_template('custom_interface_4.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


include your source code as well. If / path works it might be related to something in your code.

OK, some progress .... I was checking/changing the nginx configuration and now the endpoints that return static HTML work fine, but the endpoints that connect to a database to return data show a 500 error

Allow port 8000 on the security group attached to your instance. That is why you can reach it locally, but not from the internet.
Also you might need to open access from ec2 to your database if it runs on separate instance.

I've done that now but still no joy.  The endpoints that return static endpoints work and the endpoints that need to query a database don't work

if database is on separate instance, you need also to allow connection  from ec2 to db on database security group.
